# Element getting unnecessary margin

Tags: html, css, margin

[image: Image of MUCAS web site]

As you can see, the nav element has a bit too much top padding. The links' outlines are in the right spot though, there's just that extra annoying space. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>'''+title+'''</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico"/>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico"/>
        <style>
            @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,700);
            html, body {
            margin: 0;
            background: #333333;
            height: 100%;
            position: relative;
            font-family: "merriweather";
            overflow-y: hidden;
            }
            h1 {
            font: bold 40pt roboto, arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            background: yellow;
            padding: 30px;
            }
            nav {
            display: inline-block;
            }
            nav a {
            cursor: pointer;
            font: bold 18px roboto;
            display: inline-block;
            transition-duration: 0.2s;
            padding: 15px 30px;
            background: linear-gradient(
            #FF9900, #FF9900 50%, #333333 50%, #333333
            /*outline: none;*/
            );
            background-size: 100% 200%;
            color: black;
            }
            nav a:hover {
            background-position: 100% 100%;
            color: yellow;
            }
            nav a:focus {
            outline:none;
            }
            #content-white-bkg {
            background: white;
            padding: 30px;
            margin: 15px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            }
            *:not(nav) > a:link {
            cursor: pointer;
            color: #FF9900;
            transition-duration: 0.35s;
            /*border-bottom: 1px solid #FF9900;*/
            }
            *:not(nav) > a:visited {
            color: #FF6600;
            cursor: pointer;
            transition-duration: 0.35s;
            }
            *:not(nav) > a:hover, *:not(nav) > a:focus {
            color: black;
            outline: none;
            }
            a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: black;
            }
            nav > a.selected {
            background: #333333;
            color: yellow;
            text-shadow: 0 0 3px #FF9900, 0 0 5px #FF9900, 0 0 7px #FF9900, 0 0 10px #FF9900, 0 0 15px #FF9900;
            transition-duration: 0.5s;
            }
            nav > a.selected:hover {
            color: #333333;
            }
            ::selection {
            background: #FF7700;
            }
            ::-webkit-selection {
            background: #FF7700;
            }
            ::-moz-selection {
            background: #FF7700;
            }
            h3 {
            font: bold 18px nunito;
            margin-top: 0;
            }                
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 title='MUCAS: Multi-User Chat Application Server'>
            <span><img width="95" height="53" title="" alt="" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-JNE2j3gX9mc/Vfn58paI2oI/AAAAAAAABRI/dqt4nqR5dZ4/w426-h238/MUCAS%2Blogo.jpeg"/></span>
            <nav><a href="/" id="nav-/" tabindex="-1">Home/chat</a><a href="/login" id="nav-/login" tabindex="-1">Log in</a><a href="/sign-up" id="nav-/sign-up" tabindex="-1">Sign up</a><a href="/about" id="nav-/about" tabindex="-1">About MUCAS</a><a href="/contact" id="nav-/contact" tabindex="-1">Contact me</a></nav>
        </h1>
        <div id="content-white-bkg">
            '''+body+'''
            <script>
                var cwb = document.getElementById("content-white-bkg");
                document.getElementById("content-white-bkg").style.height = (window.innerHeight-200)+"px";
                window.onresize = function() {
                    document.getElementById("content-white-bkg").style.height = (window.innerHeight-200)+"px";
                }
                var path = window.location.pathname;
                document.getElementById("nav-"+path).className = "selected";
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can anybody help me with this? Is it a layout issue, or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
nav a {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: @ErikIsaksen, this property is also interpreted with inline-block display. I tried it out on a fiddle, it works.

Comment: That worked, but there's still a little extra bottom padding.

Comment: It may not be padding. You could also set `vertical-align: top` to other elements there. But some of that apparent padding is also to do with alignment with the image. It might be worth setting up a working demo if you need more assistance.

Answer (score 0):

check the developer tools in your browser. Select the nav element and view the CSS panel associated with that element. Look at the inherited styles and the computed style. Is the margin or padding on the nav inheriting? Maybe it is a parent or child element of it is computed to zero. This could be the links, list, list items, or parent. If you can use flexbox I highly recommend it for aligning components and layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
nav {
   vertical-align: super;
}
```

"vertical-align: super" will treat your "nav" as a superscript. I tried putting it in your code and found it works. You can try if you think it can solve your problem. Thanks.

Comment: Please explain your answer, short answer might get removed or you will get down votes

Comment: @eirenaios thanks. I am very new to stackoverflow. I am trying to get used to with it. Should i remove this answer to avoid down vote? please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
nav a {
    float: left;
}
```

I should also change the h1 to a div element for semantics. h1 is used for example a page title and not to wrap a navigation bar and an logo in..

Answer (score 0):

You are doing several things wrong here.
You are placing a navigation item and image inside of an header element. You are not using float for the elements you want to float.

Use a  around it instead.

I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9fwgdkrc/) illustrating the float, without correcting the semantics.

Consider doing something like this instead:

```
<div class="header">
<img src="image.jpg">
<nav>...links here...</nav>
</div>
```